# Invalid env setting in dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, alpine-linux

The env setting in docker cannot take effect in ENTRYPOINT, but it can be used normally after entering the container

You can see the environment variable settings of MYSQL_DB below

Remarks:
Because I want to dynamically set ENV through a script, when I write the Dockerfile, I don’t know which environment variables are there, so there is no way to use ENV in the dockerfile to set environment variables. I can only dynamically introduce environment variables with the RUN command.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.8
ENV ENV="/etc/profile" 
RUN echo "export MYSQL_DB=127.0.0.1" >> "$ENV"
RUN echo "env && echo '************' && tail -f /etc/profile">/tmp/test.sh

ENTRYPOINT  ["sh","tmp/test.sh"]
```

run Dockerfile

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t test . && docker run --name test -p 3333:3000 -itd test && docker logs -f test
```

docker logs

```
HOSTNAME=dcb1372343c0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
ENV=/etc/profile
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
************
export PAGER=less
export PS1='\h:\w\$ '
umask 022

for script in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
        if [ -r $script ] ; then
                . $script
        fi
done
export MYSQL_DB=127.0.0.1
```

exec docker print env

```
➜  nodejs_dist git:(master) ✗ docker exec -it test /bin/sh                                                                                                    
dcb1372343c0:/# env
HOSTNAME=dcb1372343c0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PAGER=less
PS1=\h:\w\$ 
ENV=/etc/profile
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
CHARSET=UTF-8
MYSQL_DB=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about your larger application?  You control everything that goes into the Dockerfile so you should know which environment variables are (or could be) set.  You should probably optimize your setup for the main container process (so setting things up in an `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper script is a good option) and not worry about `docker exec` debugging shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/profile` only called within `login shell` while `sh` default works in `non login shell` mode.

One solution maybe as next to change it to force using logic shell:

```
ENTRYPOINT  ["sh","-l","tmp/test.sh"]
```

Execution result:

```
$ docker run abc:1
HOSTNAME=11a873681051
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PAGER=less
PS1=\h:\w\$
ENV=/etc/profile
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
CHARSET=UTF-8
MYSQL_DB=127.0.0.1
************
export PAGER=less
export PS1='\h:\w\$ '
umask 022

for script in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
        if [ -r $script ] ; then
                . $script
        fi
done
export MYSQL_DB=127.0.0.1
```